# C# open rasphone.exe with arguments

Tags: c#, visual-studio, parameters, vpn, openprocess

Can you find my problem?
I can't open rasphone.exe with the right arguments.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo proc = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    proc.FileName = @"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe";
    proc.Arguments = @"C:\Windows\System32\rasphone.exe -d ""My VPN""";
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(proc);
}
```

I also tried:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\rasphone.exe", @" -d ""My VPN"" ");
```

Or:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\\Users\\***\\Documents\\VPN Launcher\\VPN Launcher\\VPN Launcher\\startVPN.bat");
```

In the .bat file:

```
start "" "C:\Windows\System32\rasphone.exe" -d "My VPN"
```

It opens the cmd/.bat but i dont open the rasphone.exe with the right arguments.

Comment: Why don't you launch rasphone.exe directly ? Do you absolutely need to get through the command line before ?

Comment: No, but it dont work. I tried it ( Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\rasphone.exe", @" -d ""My VPN"" "); )

Comment: Does rasphone starts when you try to launch manually with that command line ?

Comment: Yes, it also starts when I start it with the batch-file or through the command line but it dont start while debugging

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that rasphone is not starting ? I mean do you keep your application running to ensure that the process you launched keeps running ?

Comment: It is starting but it dont show the window where the user can login the vpn. It shows some arguments like (-a .. -e ... some informations) but not the login window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow. As [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo_Arguments) said, you need to escape double-quotas with **3** double-quotas:) I don't know why it is mandatory, but this should work:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\System32\rasphone.exe", "-d \"\"\"My VPN\"\"\"");
```

Comment: It's a step forward :) But I get the message: "Command Prompt for the dial-up network" with some arguments/informations. But nothing to login.